# Swift Package issue with SwiftUI and Cannot find type 'View' in scope

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I am attempting to create a Swift Package to include some common views that I use.  When I try to archive the app, this shows up `Cannot find type 'View' in scope`.  The app runs correctly on device and in simulator. Error occurs wherever `View` appears in the code that is from the Swift Package.

Example of the view:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
public struct ErrorView: View {
    public var errorText: String?
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "xmark.octagon")
                    .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            Text(errorText!)
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
    public init(errorText: String) {
        self.errorText = errorText
    }
}
```

Comment: So, whatever package you are using has a type called `View`?

Comment: I am creating the package and the only place `View` exist is in the `SwiftUI View` shown above.

Answer (score 2):

I after adding `platforms:` to the package.swift the issue was resolved.

```
platforms: [
        .iOS(.v14),
        .macOS(.v11)
    ],
```

Also changed `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` to `@available(iOS 14, macOS 11.0, *)` for helping make sure no other issue come up with the views.